# linked list and segmentation fault error in my code

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

my code is the following: it asks the user to input name of planet, distance, and a description. Then it will print out whatever the user entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* planet type */
typedef struct{
  char name[128];
  double dist;
  char description[1024];
} planet_t;

/* my planet_node */
typedef struct planet_node {
  char name[128];
  double dist;
  char description[1024];
  struct planet_node *next;
} planet_node;

/* the print function, not sure if its correct */
void print_planet_list(planet_node *ptr){
  while(ptr != NULL){
    printf("%s %lf %s\n", ptr->name, ptr->dist, ptr->description);
    ptr=ptr->next;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(){
  char buf[64];
  planet_node *head = NULL;
  int quit = 0;

  do {
    printf("Enter planet name (q quits): ");
    scanf("%s",buf);
    if((strcmp(buf,"q")==0)){
      quit = 1;
    }
    else{
      planet_node *new = malloc(sizeof(planet_node));       /* New node */
      strcpy((*new).name, buf);         /* Copy name */
      printf("Enter distance and description: ");
      scanf(" %lf ", new->dist); /* Read a new distance into pluto's */
      gets(new->description);      /* Read a new description */
      new->next = head;        /* Link new node to head */
      head=new;        /* Set the head to the new node */
    }
  } while(!quit);

  printf("Final list of planets:\n");
  print_planet_list(head);


  while(head != NULL){
    planet_node *remove = head;
    head = (*head).next;
    free(remove);
  }
}
```

the places where i made comments are the where i am not sure if it is correct, the code complies but gives me a segmentation error.
any help? thanks.

Comment: Did you compile your code with all warnings and debugging information (on Linux use `gcc -Wall -g`)? Then improve the code till no warnings are given. At last use a debugger (`gdb` on Linux) and a leak detector (`valgrind` on Linux) to debug.

Comment: I don't get an error in VC (compile or run). Though I did change "new" - that's a keyword in C++.

Comment: @MarkStevens but not in `C`. So it compiles fine if you use .c extension.

Comment: @PrototypeStark: I know, just feels funny to call a variable "new" ;)

Comment: @MarkStevens Yeah I know ;) :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf(" %lf ", new->dist);`

This is where your error is.
 It should be:

`scanf(" %lf ", &(new->dist));`

Also an extra ' ' causes it to accept extra characters. This can be avoided with

`scanf("%lf", &(new->dist));`

Comment: Notice that this error would have been caught by `gcc -Wall` which issues a warning.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch unfortunately I don't have gcc, but I caught it at first reading. :P. Compiler in my head is slower but more accurate(i think) :D

Comment: Just for reference, the actual warning is "test.c:44:7: warning: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat]
test.c:60:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]"

Comment: Thanks @harpun I am seriously considering installing cygwin and gcc/g++. Its more in use on SO these days.